# B2B Commerce Cloud related Product

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

I am trying to add related product for a parent product. I have set up a parent and child product in commerce cloud with product relationship object. But when i select the parent product form community page the related child products are not visible. Can anyone please share how can this be achieved.
Document url used for setting up the relationship :  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.comm_product_sets_configure.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to remember is to ensure that you rebuild your product index from the administration page.

Your new products won't appear until you rebuild the product index.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  But I tried it already its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This feature exist just in LWR storefront template.
If you are tring to do it with Aura B2B template it will not work.
In LWR template you have to select another component that called 'product set'